# Output resolution issue for r.forestfrag in GRASS

Tags: python, raster, grass-gis, resolution

I've been trying to calculate forest fragmentation index for a 1kmx1km (30 arcsecs) raster using r.forestfrag in GRASS. I was expecting an output raster of the same resolution but the output I'm getting is at a resolution of 1 degree. How can I adjust this? I hope I'm not missing out on something obvious. I would like to use a moving window of 9 pixels so that the index for the central pixel can be calculated based on the immediate neighbourhood as explained in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/26271763.pdf). I don't have much experience using GIS with Python, so is there any way I can modify the code? If not, then is there any other way I could implement the same functionality either in Python or R? [Here is the link to the documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.forestfrag.html).

Comment: In GRASS, you must set your computational region. This is FAQ #0 :-). Check your current region settings with `g.region -p`. Then set to something else with, i.e. `g.region res=0.00833`. (Note that 30 arcsec is not exactly 1 km!)

Comment: @Micha Wow this worked like a charm. Thank you!